# Wrapping string interpolator macro in another

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-reflect

I have interpolator `xxx` is implemented by macro (I do own the code) and returns XXX. I want to implement interpolator `yyy` when I have function `f: XXX => YYY`

The  code

```
class XXXMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  final def xxx(args: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[XXX] = {
      val Apply(_, Apply(_, parts) :: Nil) = c.prefix.tree
      ???
  }
}

implicit class XXXInterpolator(sc: StringContext) {
  def xxx(args: Any*): XXX = macro XXXMacro.xxx
}

class YYYMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  final def yyy(args: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[YYY] = q"yyy($xxx\"args\")"
}

implicit class YYYInterpolator(sc: StringContext) {
  def yyy(args: Any*): YYY = macro XXXMacro.yyy
}
```

Problem is that I can not easily parametrise the code. Compiler won't let me to do `macro XXXMacro(f).yyy`  or `macro XXXMacro.yyy(f)`.

Also when I wrap it like `def yyy(args: Any*): YYY = f(new XXXInterpolator(sc).xxx(args))` context in macro is completely different and complicate it and I can't reuse it. Any way how to  make it easier?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
class XXXMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  final def xxx(args: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[XXX] = {
    val Apply(_, Apply(_, parts) :: Nil) = c.prefix.tree
    ???
  }

  final def yyy(args: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[YYY] =
    reify {
      f(xxx(args: _*).splice)
    }
}

implicit class XXXInterpolator(sc: StringContext) {
  def xxx(args: Any*): XXX = macro XXXMacro.xxx
}

implicit class YYYInterpolator(sc: StringContext) {
  def yyy(args: Any*): YYY = macro XXXMacro.yyy
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dmytro-mitin. I do not  wanted  XXXMacro to depend on YYY class but  I found a solution

Answer (score 2):

I do not want XXXMacro to depend on YYY. So the solution is to user `trait` and  `Tree`

```
trait XXXMacroTree {
  val c: blackbox.Context
  import c.universe._

  final def xxxTree(args: c.Expr[Any]*): Tree = ???

  final def xxx(args: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[XXX] = c.Expr[XXX](xxxTree(args: _*))
}
class XXXMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) extends XXXMacroTree

implicit class XXXInterpolator(sc: StringContext) {
  def xxx(args: Any*): XXX = macro XXXMacro.xxx
}

class YYYMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) extends XXXMacroTree {
  import c.universe._

  final def yyy(args: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[YYY] = c.Expr[YYY](q"f(${xxxTree(args: _*)}))
}

implicit class YYYInterpolator(sc: StringContext) {
  def yyy(args: Any*): YYY = macro YYYMacro.yyy
}
```